# Displaying Images with theme filter

Tags: twig

So I'm having a weird problem since migrating a Winter CMS website from my development hosting to a client's server in that all of the images have disappeared.

I had been using, for example,

```
<img src="{{ url('') }}/themes/assets/images/logos/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="img-fluid" />
```

to display images, which worked fine on my development server. After migration, however, the `src` attribute of all image tags became `src(unknown)`. I have been told to use

```
<img src="{{ 'assets/images/logos/logo.png' | theme }}" >
```

Which also causes `src(unknown)`. However, when testing, if I use

```
<p>{{ 'assets/images/logos/logo.png' | theme }}</p>
```

I can see the correct path for the image. Does anyone know why this won't work when used as a `src` attribute, but works fine in `<p>` tags?

Comment: Did you update the setting `url` in `config/app.php`? Make sure you use `https://` if the site is using SSL

Comment: I do have that properly configured.

The twig tag is printing the full path of the file correctly when used outside of an image's src attribute.

Comment: You could try to do `{% set url = 'assets/images/logos/logo.png' | theme %}` and then use `url` as the source

Comment: That results in the same behaviour - I get the correct path for the image if I use `{{ url }}` between <p> tags, but src(unknown) if I use it in the src attribute.

This is really weird!!

Comment: Where do you see this `src(unknown)` then? Did you check the actual sourcecode ? CTRL+ U

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific as to where I was seeing that - that is appearing in Chome's developer tools. In the source code it is `src=""`

Could it be to do with the quotation marks? I've tried both double and single quotation marks and both result in the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

On the off-chance that anyone experiences the same problem, I found that disabling the `Offline.ResponsiveImages` plugin solved the issue.

This can't explain why 2 of the 3 environments performed better, but I hope it helps someone one day.